# How to connect to cpanel mysql database from localhost

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, cpanel

I am trying to connect to the mysql database from my express server in cpanel (the databse and server are both in cpanel) , I already added a user, and I'm trying to connect via localhost but this ain't working
below is the code:

```
const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: \\user\\,
  password: \\password\\,
  database: "ts34mpr_SCMP",
  dateStrings: true,
});
```

The request isn't reaching the databse although I added the user with all privileges and the user with password are 100% correct.
Any help please?
Thank you!

Comment: First you need some step to access your cpanel database in your local computer.please read this article it will help you a lot

Comment: what article? and I'm not trying to access it remotely, what I'm trying to do is to run the express server which is in cpanel (and the express server needs to access the db which is also on cpanel) the struggle is that I think the credentials are wrong

Comment: instead of localhost as the host name could you change the db host name mentioned in cpanel db configuration. https://www.knownhost.com/kb/how-to-connect-to-mysql-remotely-in-cpanel/

Comment: I tried adding my hostname which is the domain but it didn't work

Comment: most of the time domain was'nt the db hostname.For testing purpose .You first get a remote access and check it working by the default configuration

Comment: @lava well it was from the root http request , I was sending it to localhost instead of sending it to the domain name :) dum........... thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can just put `%` to allow all (https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/allow-any-host-to-connect-to-mysql-remotely.189131/post-774871), or you can put the ip address where you will get the error like `Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'db_name'@'491.25.***.***' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'cpanel'
});
```

Comment: nope, the database isn't called cpanel, the server the cloud is called so